# How to use a global variable and file data in a seperate function in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct, global-variables

So basically my program reads a char array, quantity and price into one function and saves it to a file. In the next function it needs to check if the two char array matches the one on the file and then use the stored price and quantity in the program.

I saved the char array (name), quantity and price in a struct and the first function saved it to a file.

Is it possible for another function to access this same file, retrieve information from the file and modify it as seen necessary?

I don't really want to post the source code as its nearly 200 lines

```
struct inventory
{
    int  item_num;
    char item_name[25];
    float item_cost;
    int item_inventory;
};

//This one takes in the inventory information
void function1( )
{
    scanf("%24s",&stock[count].item_name);
    scanf("%f",&stock[count].item_cost);
    scanf("%d",&stock[count].item_inventory);
    FILE *stockfile;
    stockfile= fopen("C:\\Users\\Varo\\Desktop\\stock.txt","w");
}

void function2()
{
    char tempname[25];
    struct inventory stock[20];
    int tempquan;

    FILE *stockfile;
    stockfile= fopen("C:\\Users\\Varo\\Desktop\\stock.txt","r");
    scanf ("%d", &tempquan);
    stock[count].item_inventory = stock[count].item_inventory - tempquan;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Rather than giving us your work to do can you try and isolate a particular issue or problem you're having? - that way you'll be able to post the relevant bits of source, if applicable.

Comment: yes you can.Also not post whole code but post  at least two function which you are talking about.

Comment: Ok I think I added in the necessary parts.I hope you can sift through my garbage